# Rule-based or Statistics-based approach for generating plain language grammar rules from a text

Tags: computational-linguistics, chinese

Disclaimer: I am a software developer, not a computational linguist and I am not super familiar (though I am mildly familiar) with the field. Happy to learn and be corrected though!

My use-case:

I am trying to analyze a text in Chinese, and have grammar rules printed out (in English) based on what appears in the text. These would be simple sentences describing the grammar rule in question.

I have explored several statistics-based parsers (Stanford, SyntaxNet, and SpaCy) and I am looking into how rule-based processing works and I'm somewhat lost - I'm not sure what the right approach is here. It seems that what I want (my guess) is a rule-based approach, and then just mapping that into plain text language - but I don't know what I don't know.

Ideally a solution would be made for Python as that's the language the rest of the application is being done in with the anticipation that most language tools will be available for it.

I am certainly open for using a tool in a different language or even a different approach entirely if that's the best idea.

Here is an example sentence:

> 人们都穿上了很厚的衣服。

This would generate, for example, this grammar rule:

Verb / Verb Phrase + 了 - Expressing that an action has been completed with "Verb / Verb Phrase + 了"

Due to detecting 了, as long as this character was being used in that particular grammatical way above.

So basically it would look for certain characters, see how they are being used in a sentence, and then spit out a plain text English language rule based on that (presumably based on some mapping of the grammar rules to plain text English that I would write)

My knowledge of computational linguistics is somewhat limited (I am a layman, though I am reading heavily every day) so I am trying to understand the best way forward for this goal.

Comment: (sorry, ignore the previous comment) I am confused as to what your goal is when you say you want to "generat[e] plain language grammar rules". Can you give an example of input and output you are envisioning? Any parser, whether rule-based or statistics-based, will output *structures* (is this what you mean by "rule"?); spaCy, for example, gives you 2 structures: constituency and dependency. The 'rules' to derive those structures from text are implicit, given the statistical nature of the parsers.

Comment: Essentially I want to have a Chinese text, and have a parser analyze this text and when it sees a piece of Chinese that has some grammar rule that applies to it, it generates plain text English language describing the rule. I'll edit my answer in a few minutes with an example.

Comment: What you mean by 'rule' is a combination of *syntactic* label (verb) plus some explanation of the label (expressing that...). To label text, you can just use an off-the-shelf parser; no need to build your own. For the explanation bit, I believe all you need is a simple mapping between labels and explanations. When you say "了" expresses "an action [that] has been completed", this to me sounds like some form of *participle* marking. For example, English parsers would tag "gone" as VBN, i.e. the past *participle* of "go", so one could map VBZ -> "an action [that] has been completed".

Comment: Though I would be good at it, I don't understand what are you trying to say. This combination [verb + 了] means something that had happened in the past and is completed now. First add more to that for me to understand. Which one are you asking, the meaning or the mapping?

Comment: @Rodrigo - yes. In fact I went with HPSG's Zhong grammar and DELPH-IN as my parser as it had far more granular rules (high specificity to Chinese specifically rather than just VBN, VBZ, etc) than the statistical parsers I had encountered.

Comment: @zixuan - Here I am describing the meaning of the rules themselves, when an instance of the rules is found in the text.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander So you want your parser to understand the rules?

Comment: @zixuan and ultimately print them out, yes. I'm guessing I'll need to do some mix of parsing the .tdl rules and also rewriting grammar rules in code. I'm not a linguist, so I am not quite sure the best way to do forward with that

Comment: Parsers and taggers are normally trained with human-labelled data, supervised.  What you want then is some unsupervised approach to learning  the rules (but not the actual parsing).  It's an interesting idea, but I'm not aware of anything approaching it.  Some related ideas are *POS language models* and this larger thread about the Thai room thought experiment: https://twitter.com/emilymbender/status/1024042044035985408

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer I’m actually using a HPSG grammar with ridiculously specific rules, and it seems to be going well so far

Comment: Then I misunderstood what you want.

Comment: Ha! Interesting finding that HSPG performs better than statistical parsers for the Chinese language you're parsing =) In any case, I hold my suggestion that all you need is a simple mapping (tag X -> explanation Y), so after the parser is done tagging your text, your system would print out explanations for each tag (or only the ones you want). This map would be *manually* built by you, although I'm quite sure you can just copy/paste from online resources. In sum, I don't see this task as language learning (statistical) or engineering (rule-base), just good old software development =)

Comment: @Rodrigo - well I needed the rules, and the HPSG rules are WAY more granular. And I definitely agree, it's not ML or engineering really, it's actually just a pretty easy mapping based on grammar rule and character in question. But I read quite a bit about HPSG (And MRS) just to understand what I did and didn't need. It's definitely been quite an interesting slough, but I feel it's been pretty valuable as, "baby's first steps into Comp Ling"!

Comment: That doesn't even make sense to me.

Comment: Glad I could help, although I must confess I'm still not 100% sure what your map will look like. Perhaps you could answer your own question with a few examples and then we can take it from there. Also glad you're enjoying HPSG and MRS; MRS is quite interesting but can be very hairy... Which is probably why formalisms like MRS seem to have stayed academic, while most of the *practical* NLP world adopted simple treebanks and, more recently dependency grammars, which is what you'll find in the likes of spaCy, NLTK, Stanford, etc.

Comment: @Rodrigo Yeah, the problem is that my domain knowledge is limited (and so is my domain-specific vocabulary!) so I am having trouble explaining cogently what I want to do. I will post an answer with my examples to give an idea of where I am. And yeah, I was surprised to find that there were basically no developer-friendly docs for HPSG at all. I actually plan on writing something up that's developer friendly when I understand everything.

Comment: @Rodrigo Sorry about the delay, this was the first time I could devote the time to it. Added a sort-of answer. It's a quick and dirty program to show a single rule (for a single POS), and I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do what I want to do, but it should show what I am generally aiming towards.

Comment: Sorry this could be asked on stack overflow but be sure what they're on topic for.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Hello I just came across this question. I'm the developer of PyDelphin and some other related software, and also I work with the people who work on the Zhong grammar. Are you still working on this task? If so I can try and answer some of your questions.

Comment: @goodmami - I am still working on this! I don't have the time to discuss it right now, but I'll comment on here again with a few questions in a few days. Thank you! I have used PyDelphin prominently in my application so far.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander sounds good. you can contact me directly or, if it's an implementation question, stackoverflow might be better suited, or even the DELPH-IN support forum: https://delphinqa.ling.washington.edu/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've got a basic example in code - I'll ultimately write my algorithm to be more efficient and right now it is only written for the one use-case (I haven't generalized it/made it so that you can have multiple daughters under a rule yet), but right now I'm just writing it out for one single rule to show an example of what I ultimately want to do.

If there is a more efficient way to do what I am doing, **PLEASE** tell me, as I don't know what I don't know on this subject. I am using PyDelphin for the analysis. **EDITTED WITH NEWEST VERSION**

```
from delphin.interfaces import ace
zhs = 'zhs.dat'

grammar = zhs

parse_string = '我 看 了 猴子 的 雪白 雪白 的 小小 的 猫'

print("PARSE STRING: " + parse_string)

with ace.AceParser(grammar,
                    cmdargs=['-n', '50']) as parser:
                        tree = parser.interact(parse_string).results()[9].derivation()

# Maybe reverse mapping so that long form POS is key?
pos_mapping = {
    'j': 'adjective',
    'pfv': 'perfective aspect',
}

def redup_post_processing(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.replace('々', phrase)
    phrase = phrase.replace('々', "")
    return phrase

def pos_generate(node):
    pos_level = node.preterminals()[0].entity
    TAG = pos_level.split("_")[1]
    POS = pos_mapping[TAG]
    return POS

def grammar_rule_gen(node, data):
    POS = pos_generate(node)
    phrase = node.terminals()[0].form
    if 'postprocess' in data.keys():
        phrase = data['postprocess'](phrase)
    print(data['text'] + POS + ' ' +  phrase)

functions = {
    'redup-olr': {"function": grammar_rule_gen, "text": "Expressing reduplication with the ", "postprocess": redup_post_processing},
    '了_pfv': {"function": grammar_rule_gen, "text": "Expressing completion with the "},
}

def tree_parse(tree):
    if hasattr(tree, 'daughters'):
        daughters = tree.daughters
        for daughter in daughters:
            if hasattr(daughter, 'entity'):
                if daughter.entity in functions:
                    functions[daughter.entity]['function'](daughter, functions[daughter.entity])
            tree_parse(daughter)

tree_parse(tree)
```

Now when I run this, it accurately gets me the rule in question that I want - here is my output:

```
PARSE STRING: 我 看 了 猴子 的 雪白 雪白 的 小小 的 猫
NOTE: parsed 2 / 2 sentences, avg 45873k, time 0.22833s
Expressing completion with the perfective aspect 了
Expressing reduplication with the adjective 雪白雪白
Expressing reduplication with the adjective 小小
```

And here is the original rule in the grammar (々 is a Japanese character used in Chinese on occasion to represent reduplication - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%80%85):

```
redup-olr :=
%suffix (* 々)
redup-lex-rule.
```

And here is the 了 rule:

```
了_pfv := pfv-marker &
  [ STEM <"了">,
    SYNSEM.LOCAL.CAT.HEAD.CHAR [ FCHAR "了", LENGTH one ],
    SYNSEM.LOCAL.CAT.VAL.COMPS < [ LOCAL.CAT.HEAD.LZG le ] >,
    TRAITS native_token_list ].
```

Now it would be awesome to just apply these rules as the text was processed - but that would require me writing an extension for ACE or a custom parser (which I guess on some level, I am sorta doing, but nowhere near as complex), and that feels **far** more complicated than what I am doing here.

Is this the most efficient way to do what I want to do?

This **IS** a solution to my problem, but I am not sure if it is the most elegant, or computationally cheap.

Comment: These Python lines of code do not work for me :(

Comment: You're using the Zhong grammar and have ACE & PyDelphin installed?

Comment: (sorry ignore my previous comment) Yep. But, it seems like to me that it says "NOTE: parsed *1* / 2 sentences, avg 231451k, time 0.95741s" to me. I've been confused that it only parsed 1 when I run it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite sure on the parsing note and why it thinks my string is two sentences - possibly because the tree is split under head-comp: http://delph-in.github.io/delphin-viz/demo/#input=%E6%88%91%20%E7%9C%8B%20%E4%BA%86%20%E7%8C%B4%E5%AD%90%20%E7%9A%84%20%E9%9B%AA%E7%99%BD%20%E9%9B%AA%E7%99%BD%20%E7%9A%84%20%E5%B0%8F%E5%B0%8F%20%E7%9A%84%20%E7%8C%AB&count=50&grammar=zhong-uw&tree=true

Comment: But right now this is essentially doing what I want it to - I'd need to write rules for each grammar rule I want (which is a bit time intensive, but I only need a couple hundred to start, so it shouldn't be awful). It'd be nice to be able to hook directly into ACE (I guess I could rewrite the Zhong grammar to use my plain english text instead of 'redup-olr', but that seems like a poor idea in case they update the grammar)

Comment: Basically it's just mapping at this point, I think, and this is probably the correct answer to my question. But I am open to ideas to make it more efficient if anyone has any

Comment: ...better answer?

Comment: Well yeah. I am essentially duplicating code here - I am parsing with ACE, and then doing mapping and postprocessing in Python. Maybe there's some way to apply TDL rules directly or something (though I suspect that's only possible with a parser, and I don't want to rewrite a parser). Basically I think I have the best solution to my problem above, but I am open to hearing new ideas

Comment: <comments duplicated to chat> Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88861/discussion-between-zixuan-and-andrew-alexander).

Comment: Very helpful example, Andrew! I can't recommend a more efficient approach, because I personally don't see how else you would do this. The only thing to worry is if the rules are very context-dependent, which is often the case in language. For example, can 了 *not* mean reduplication in certain contexts? That is precisely the reason why the best parsers (for Engish, at least) are statistical. But they require, as you know, a large amount of training data, which could be very difficult for you to gather by yourself. So, if your approach does the trick in most cases, then I'd say carry on!

Comment: @Rodrigo So that seems to be a huge benefit of the HPSG Zhong grammar - while the rules are context dependent, it seems to catch the vast majority of use-cases with very, very granular rules. I'll likely have to tweak it (either by using a modified form of the original grammar which I edit or postprocessing in the mapper), but for the most part it seems to have even greater granularity than statistical parsers would (which would essentially just give me very basic POS - N, V, ADV, etc)

Comment: http://delph-in.github.io/delphin-viz/demo/#input=%E8%BF%99%20%E4%B8%A4%20%E4%B8%AA%20%E8%AF%8D%20%E7%9A%84%20%E6%84%8F%E6%80%9D%20%E5%B7%AE%E4%B8%8D%E5%A4%9A&count=50&grammar=zhong-uw&tree=true - as you can see here, the rules show a great deal of language-specific granularity!

Statistical parsers are probably better for most functions, but I think for my specific use-case, this is probably the way to go. I've got 50 rules written up so far at this point, and for the most part everything seems to be working well.